# Нет перевода содержимого тега <title> при сортировке вопросов по рейтингу

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Если отсортировать вопросы по рейтингу, то можно увидеть, что `<title>` страницы не переведён:

> `<title>Highest scored questions - Stack Overflow на русском</title>`

Наблюдается как и на основном сайте, так и на Мете.

Comment: [Нет строк для перевода](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375969/339911), надо ждать пока добавят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможность переводов добавили. А я добавил группу переводов по подстроке ["ighest score"](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=ighest%20score).

Должно появиться на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2022.2.7.41389